# PHP, filter specific words using str_replace

Tags: php

Basically, I currently have this line of code:

```
$uname = str_replace(array('!','"','£','$','%','%','^','&','*','(',')','-','+','=','\\','/','[',']','{','}',';',':','@','#','~','<',',','>','.','?','|',' '), '', $uname);
```

**I know it is messy, I've never used it before in this 'context'**

Anyway, is there anyway I could have another array for bad words? example:

```
$uname = str_replace(array)('!','"','£','$','%','%'), '', $uname);
         str_replace(array)('badword1','badword2'), '****', $uname);
```

The above is basically what I want, however if their is a neater way to do it Ill do it like that, however any help is welcome.

Comment: Are you asking if you can run `str_replace` twice on the same data?

Comment: Basically. I want it to block out special characters, and replace them with a space, and block out bad words and replace them with 'badword'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need to create two or more instances of `str_replace()` since it is possible to replace as many words as possible using just one.

First, you must make a "group" of every bad word you wish to filter and put them inside an `array`.

#### # `Example:`

```
$bannedWords = array('shit', 'john mccain', 'jack and jill', 'IE6');
```

Then you might probably want to check first, if a variable includes a word from your list of banned words. For this you can use PHP's [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function:

```
if(in_array($_POST['keyword'], $bannedWords)){

   // keyword not allowed, 
}
```

After this, if you wish to replace the word, then use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) as:

```
$replaced = str_replace($bannedWords, "", $_POST['keyword']);
```

This will remove all words and replace them with nothing, if you had passed `"x"` instead of `""` as the second argument, then they would all have been replaced with `x`

#### # finally:

You can define a unique word to replace every unique banned word, by passing an array as the second argument of `str_replace`:

```
str_replace(['IE6', 'mccain', 'shit'], ['FireFox', 'roosevelt', 'Cake'], $_POST['keyword'])
```

Now from `$_POST['keyword']` the word IE6 will be Replaced with FireFox with, mccain with roosevelt and so on..

Comment: I understand that part, thats what I have for it to replace special characters, however I want a separate part to block out bad words.. sorry if I explained it badly.

Comment: Block as in what? you could just replace the `"love"` with `""` and it is done!

Comment: currently I have it so it changes special characters (*$"£$&) to a '' in one str_replace, I want to add another str_replace to change bad words to good words, I know how to make one str_replace.. but not how to make.. two and change data. Kind of like a text to img thing on a forum where it changes : ) to a img.

Comment: What do you mean seperate and block. because, for seperate you can create a separate `str_replace` or you can create list of bad words and keep them inside an array. I'll update my answer @Laim

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted, sorry for my terrible explanation :P Thank you @php NoOb :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$remove = new Array("noob", "racist", "hate", "gay", "etc");
$text = str_replace($remove, "", $post);
echo $text;
```

This is a way of doing this. If you are getting the string from post, you can make a remove array, the make a text variable that replaces the array with a `""` from the post. You can echo the text, NOT post, then any of the words that was in the array will not be show when the echo text is show.